# Using pcregrep with --color option - only highlight non captured expression?

Tags: pcre, pcregrep

I would like to use pcregrep with its --color option to highlight text that follows a particular pattern:

e.g. if file.txt contains:

```
bob says hi
chloe says hello
```

then running:

```
pcregrep --color '(?:says)(.*)' file.txt
```

prints

bob **says hi**

chloe **says hello**

but what I want is:

bob says **hi**

chloe says **hello**

Is there a way to use pcregrep and have it only highlight text that follows a particular regular expression?

Comment: Does `'says\K.*'` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be no, you cannot color only part of a match, even if it's non-capturing with `(?:..)` as in your example.

But if you instead use a positive lookbehind assertion, which anchors the match but is not part of it, you can achieve what you want:

```
pcregrep --color '(?<=says)(.*)' data
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works - not very intuitive.

I'm actually using this to highlight the method in Soap XML logs:

pcregrep --color '(?<=soap:Body><)(.*?)\s'

Comment: pcregrep must be buffering data, because using it conjunction with a tail -f doesn't work.